# Samsung Galaxy 4 GT 19505

Tags: sync

How do I stop apps from enabling high tech users to access my messages, call logs, emails, photos, samsung memos etc?

How can I save all text messages, call logs, photos, documents, downloads and everything else on my phone to a private and secure cloud domain without hackers knowing I did so?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you [put each question in a separate question post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154). Please [edit] your post down to one question, and create new posts to ask any further questions. You'll get better answers that way. Apart from that, for your 1st question you'll need to elaborate a little more: what kind of apps you're talking about? Maybe those you'd better not install? Or something that comes pre-installed?